# How to change Timeline's output time from "Frames" to "Timecode" (Premiere Pro)

Tags: premiere, framerate, timecode

I was editing a video for a friend when I accidentally changed my Timeline's timestamps from "Timecode" to Frames"
[image: Frames]

It has been really frustrating to figure out what second of footage I am on when this is occurring.
Is there any way to go back to a standard Timecode when this happens?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-click or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-click the number and it will cycle through the different modes, frames, feet & frames, audio samples, milliseconds, and timecode. More about it in the [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/timecode.html#change_how_timecode_is_displayed).